# O（k*N^2）kがNと同じと考えられる場合

Tags: 計算量

O（k*N^2）kがNと同じと考えられる場合O(N^3)のようにまとめることは出来ますか？
例えばNxNの行列とN次元ベクトルの掛け算の場合O（N^2）となりますが
N回行った場合O(N^3)のようにまとめてもいいのですか？

Answer (score 6):

k=cN+e(N)  (cは定数、e(x)はxの1次未満の項からなる式、例えばlog(N)とか) と表せる関係があるなら、もちろんO(k*N^2)はO(N^3)です。